# get each date for two different time for 3 years

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create table in which want data like 
[shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwyRb.jpg)

which has 3 columes shift_date, shift# and Shift_startTime.
 for each day there going to be shift 1 and shift 2 , for shift 1 shift_startTime will be 6:30 and for shift 2 its 16:20 upto 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use recursive cte:

```
with cte1 as (
    select cast('2017-04-01' as datetime) as [Shift_Date], 
        cast(1 as smallint) as [Shift#],
        cast('2017-04-01 06:30:00.000' as datetime) as [Shift_StartTime]
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_Date]), [Shift#], dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_StartTime])
    from cte1
    where dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_Date]) <= '2020-12-31'
), cte2 as (
    select cast('2017-04-01' as datetime) as [Shift_Date], 
        cast(2 as smallint) as [Shift#],
        cast('2017-04-01 16:30:00.000' as datetime) as [Shift_StartTime]
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_Date]), [Shift#], dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_StartTime])
    from cte2
    where dateadd(day, 1, [Shift_Date]) <= '2020-12-31'
)
select * 
into dbo.test_shift_date_table --use you table name
from cte1
union all
select * 
from cte2
option(maxrecursion 32000)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the WHILE statement in T-SQL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql).

You can create a WHILE loop that inserts the two rows for the shifts and increases a variable by one day (with the DATEADD statemant).

Break the loop if the day variable is above year 2020.